# Externalizing MDB configurations in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, message-driven-bean

I'm using Jboss as 7.1.1 and I have my EJB MDB annotation such as below:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "XXX.IN"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "XXX.com"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "3434"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "A01"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "CLIENT.TO") }, name = "MQMDB")
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
...
```

}

I know it can be moved to ejb-jar.xml but can I move this configuration out of the code and into jboss standalone.xml file?

The reason is we will be having seperate standalone.xml for each of our environments like dev, test and live and therefore would prefer to move all the configurations out of the application deployment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to externalize your configuration is to place you activation properties in an ejb-jar.xml file:

```
<activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property-name>hostName</activation-config-property-name>
    <activation-config-property-value>${wmq.host}</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
```

Note that the value uses the property substitution syntax:

```
${wmq.host}
```

Add properties as needed for the values that you wish to replace.

Then, in your standalone.xml, ensure that spec replacement is enabled:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
    <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
    <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
    <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
</subsystem>
```

Finally, add your properties to your standalone.xml file:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="wmq.host" value="10.0.0.150"/>
    <property name="wmq.port" value="1414"/>
    <property name="wmq.queue.manager" value="MY.QUEUE.MANAGER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without ejb-jar.xml,
add

```
<annotation-property-replacement>true</annotation-property-replacement>
```

in

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
```

and in your mdb class set properties, as same as below

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "${hostName}")
```

define the System Properties in standalone.xml

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="hostName" value="1.1.1.1"/>
</system-properties>
```